# Checking for virus and malware in a Wordpress site.

Tags: php, wordpress, security

I just switched from a shared hosting to a VPS one. Before I didn't pay much attentions about security of my clients (who use WP) were taking a cautious care of preventing their sites from malwares/viruses that could be introduced from WP, because at this point if something had gone wrong my service providers would've detected the threat and would've disabled only that site. But now that I have a VPS, and my sites as well as my clients are hosted in the same root folder, I am thinking that I should monitor what my clients are doing to avoid any malicious entering out server.

As a result, I have updated all software to latest and recommended versions, like using PDO instead of mysql, and set php.ini detectives to the best secure settings, and I have striped the ability of my clients from uploading any themes (Since the sites were given for free) and I have given upload folders strict permissions, so as nothing executable is uploaded to the server, and I am doing regular database/data backups.

So, what I am looking for now is not necessarily how to make the servers more secure. But, in the unlikeliest case that something bad is uploaded/found.. how do I detect it and how would I shut down that specific website so as it does not spread or infect other files.

Answer (score 0):

do you have access to server?
you can tried with lmd [(linux malmware detect)](https://www.rfxn.com/projects/linux-malware-detect/) for know more about this

Comment: I have access to my server. I can do the routine checkups like history, last .... your link is interesting and I will check it out

Answer (score 0):

There is new virus in WP

> There's a downloading of a update.exe initiated by line
>   `<script src="//socialstatsplugin.com/jqury.js"></script>`

i Have done some reviews for this kind of virus.

Just go to your WP folder and check if any unwanted hidden file and when you browse through that , the files are unreadable.

As said Just do `DELETE FROM wp_options WHERE option_name like '%wp_data_newa%'` and
delete all unwanted hidden folder within any folder.
It worked till now. Hope it will help. Never knows the future.

Thanks